# uwp Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I found a crash on App Center, which reports that

ComCallHelpers.Call (__ComObject, RuntimeTypeHandle, Int32, Type__Impl.UnsafeType, Void*, Void*)

Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException: The text associated with this error code could not be found. Cannot create instance of type 'SMPlayer.MediaControl' [Line: 0 Position: 0]

Below is the code of my MediaControl.xaml.

[image: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acgUZ.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acgUZ.png)]

This crash doesn't occur very often but it does affect a few users. What's wrong with my MediaControl? I believe this error means my xaml file has some illegal text but what is line 0 position 0? It is really confusing.

[image]

--- Update ---

This is my code for handling the crash

```
    private void App_UnhandledException(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        Log.Error("App_UnhandledException {0}", e.Exception);
        if (e.Exception is XamlParseException) 
        {
            return;
        }
        e.Handled = true;
        Helper.ShowEmailFeedbackNotification("UnknownExceptionOccurred", "UnknownExceptionOccurredEmailTitle", Helper.GetStackTraceMessage());
    }
```

But I'm still getting new non-xaml crashes.

[image]
[image]

Comment: There is no further information about this issue. Based on the error message, the only information we know is that the creation of `MediaControl` object failed. I'd suggest you check how you created the `MediaControl` object first.  It will be helpful to ask users to collect more information like reproduce steps.

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT I didn't use any special technique to create it. And this problem seems to occur to only a few users, not every single user. I did receive a comment saying that my app crash on start so I am thinking that is it possible that I might used some resources that their computers don't support?

Comment: It's hard to dig it further if we don't have more information. What you mentioned might be a possible reason. And is it possible that other users will meet this issue when running the app for a while not only when the app start? So it's better to know the real scenario of the users who are meeting this issue.

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT I just checked all the stack traces of crash reports. They all happened on the app launch. I also posted a snapshot of that crash report.

Comment: It's still unclear why the issue happens, just knowing when it happens. I'd suggest you handle the application.unhandledexception to prevent the app from crashing.

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT Actually, I have implemented the UnhandledException long time ago by doing `public App()  {
            // other code
            this.UnhandledException += App_UnhandledException;
        }
        private void App_UnhandledException(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            Log.Error("App_UnhandledException {0}", e.Exception);
        }`, but it is still crashing.

Comment: Based on the code, it is expected that the app will crash. Your code just logs the exception information and it does not handle the exception. This is correct if you only want to check the reason for the crash. But if you want to handle the exception to prevent the crash, please add `e.Handled = true;` in the event.

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT Is it possible that I used `AcrylicBrush` in `MediaControl` and some devices don't support that? I just updated the code snapshot with `MediaControl`'s resources.

Comment: `AcrylicBrush` needs 10.0.16299 or higher version of Windows. If your min target version is lower than 10.0.16299, then this is possible to be the reason for the crash.

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT Bad news, I got crash from higher versions like10.0.22631.

Comment: You could update a version which handles the crash first.

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT Hello, I updated my code for handling the crash, which you can see from the updated area of my question. But I still get new crashes, do you know why? By the way, how can I fix them? Especially when I don't know which line of code is wrong or which file has the bug code...